# Meteor $push multipoint array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, meteor, push

I set coordinates in a geolocation array:

```
Crowds.insert({ 
    location: {"type": "MultiPoint","coordinates":
        [[1, 1]]
     }
});
Crowds._ensureIndex({ location: "2dsphere" });
```

Then I try to add value. To do so I make a §push to add new value in "coordinates" array:

```
Crowds.update(
    { _id: crowd[0]._id },
    { $push: { location: { "coordinates": [ 2, 2 ]
    }}}     
);
```

I get the folling error:

```
Exception in Mongo write: TypeError: object is not a function
```

It seems that I am not updating coordinates array the proper way... I tried various combinations but cannot find how to add value in a nested array...

Please help ;) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is there a typo there?

```
crowd[0]._id
```

"crowd" is singular there, yet you're calling [0] as if it's an array.

Should it be:

```
crowds[0]._id
```

Comment: crowd[0]._id is a simple variable, I don't think it causes error because without the $push there is no error.

Comment: @Krem, Kindly give schema example it will be useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem, and actually I didn't ask the question well... sorry

The following code returned error:

```
Crowds.update(
    { _id: '123' },
    { $inc: { people: 1 } },
    { $push: { "location.coordinates": [ Meteor.user().profile.location.coords.longitude, Meteor.user().profile.location.coords.latitude ],
    { $set: { modified: new Date().valueOf() } },
            function(error){
           return "Update error: " + error;
       }                    
);
```

But it works with:

```
Crowds.update(
    { _id: '123' },
    { $inc: { people: 1 } },
    { $set: { modified: new Date().valueOf() } },
    function(error){
        return "Update error: " + error;
    }                   
);

Crowds.update(
    { _id: crowd[0]._id },
    { $push: { "location.coordinates": [ Meteor.user().profile.location.coords.longitude, Meteor.user().profile.location.coords.latitude ]
    }},
    function(error){
      return "Update error: " + error;
    }                   
);
```

It seems that $push needs to be used alone, tell me if I am wrong in diagnostic ;)